# Blender API. Access face coordinates on image texture and UV map

Tags: scripting, uv, texture-coordinates

What I have:
Model with texture atlases inside material slots

What I need to do:
Iterate over faces of my mesh (done)
Find what texture atlas (material slot index) face using (done)
Get pixel coordinates on image texture corresponding to UV of this face.

Like this in pseudocode:

```
for face in faces:
    for vert in face.verts:
        vert_texture_coordinates = UVMap.get_coordinates(vert)
        # And here I want to get something like (13, 37)
        # representing pixel on my image texture
```

For now I only have data from bmesh.loops and have no idea what to do with it:

```
for face in faces:
    for loop in face.loops:
        uv = loop[uv_layer].uv
        # Getting <Vector (0.1116, 0.9408)>
```

[image: visual explanation]